# Can my friends join me through VPN as they would be in my lan network?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I would like to create some game servers in my house but unfortunately my IPS don't want to assign me a static public ip and open ports to my router. My question is can my friends see me (as they would be in my lan network) and connect to my game server through VPN? I have Oracle Free Tier vps and I could create OpenVPN server to let them join it. I know there are soulutions like Hamachi but I would to create my own server mainly due to high ping in and members limit.

Comment: Please proof-read your acronyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Check out [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/), which does VPN - but in a meshed fashion, so that after talking to a central server for coordination, each of your machines talk directly.

Basically, you and all your friends should install this on your gaming machines, plus install it on your gaming server. It will assign all machines (workstations + servers) a new IP which runs on an overlay (VPN) network, and you'll be done.

You'll need to configure each machine to connect to the same VPN.

You will then be able to run your server on your local (home) Lan or on a VPS with some hosting provider. Either way, it will work.

Comment: OP says they want to run their own OpenVPN server.

Comment: No. OP said they _could_ run their own OpenVPN server. I am merely suggesting an alternative. I think the reason _OP_ wants to "create their own server" is not for the VPN server, but for the gaming server. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: no, they explcitly said "I don't want to use Hamachi", which is a VPN server.

Comment: yeah, and I'm not suggesting that they use "Hamachi" or any other "VPN Server" -- its not needed to achieve what the OP wants, which is an overlay network with a reasonable latency.  Tailscale is not a "VPN Server" -- its a a mesh VPN overlay network. There is no sever needed, except for authentication, after that all VPN links do not go via any server. So I maintain that it is a good solution to the OPs needs.

Comment: ah, you want to run in meshed mode (I know tailscale, love that they do wireguard at scale) – that won't work for OP; they can't accept incoming UDP. But indeed, instead of openvpn, OP could just do Wireguard on their oracle machine. That works. (but doesn't do L2 VPN, only L3 – which might or might not be OK for the use case; same applies to tailscale)

Comment: I think it will work -- udp over wireguard works ,and if every participating host on the wireguard mesh is running the gaming software (server or client) then it should most definitely work as long as the machine involved all use the wireguard interface IPs.

Comment: It cannot work, that's the whole premise of the question: *unfortunately my IPS don't want to assign me a static public ip and open ports to my router*; closed ports on the router means your local machine cannot be the peer that another machine connects to. OP needs to be the one to initiate the (logical) connection from his home machine. Hence, they indeed are required to run a VPN server of *some* sort externally.

Comment: tailscale handles this with UDP punch-through AFAIK. See https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/

Comment: hah! Yeah, that would sound like fun, but then you still need the central server to communicate the target addresses and ports.

Comment: which is exactly what tailscale provides with its "coordination server", which I think uses standard HTTP, so is unlikely to be blocked. Once the nodes get the IPs and ports, then its UDP punch-through p2p mesh from that point onward.

Comment: quite interesting, indeed.

Comment: It is fascinating. and the guys from Tailscale are _hardcore_ -- check out Avery Pennarun's blog, in particular this post: https://apenwarr.ca/log/20170810 -- the guy knows a thing or two about networking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However, I suspect that the public VPNs will not work. The ones that you see advertised everywhere, are designed to connect you to the internet at a different access point ( to make it look like you are in a different country).  Your local network is not (directly) on the internet. If you friend can not connect then nether can a VPN. Maybe they have a switch to turn on two way connections, but this is a security risk.

Instead you need to set up a VPN. You will need a public IP on some server somewhere. You can then use ssh port forwarding (or other tool). Be vary careful with security.

Comment: OP says they want to run their own OpenVPN server. They already have a server with a public IP address. They are already beyond doing SSH forwardings.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. That's literally what VPN stands for — a virtual private network.

Your proposed OpenVPN can do exactly that: make your and your friend's machines part of a virtual layer 3 (IP) or even deeper, layer 2 (Ethernet) network. In general, you'd want to operate on layer 3, as that's easier, lower in overhead and less problematic in practice.